# Image Asset in Android Studio become weird

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, icons

I am sorry if my question is too bad. I am working on creating image asset in Android Studio but everytime I did it, every icon become weird. I also try to imported another file but it just hit the same thing[image]

Comment: What do you mean with weird?

Comment: You can see that these icons kind of "broken' in the preview window

Comment: What is the source of your SVG? Are any warnings given when importing it?

Comment: I use Image Asset from Android Studio. I also tried to import SVG with another file and there is no warning given

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling "new Layout Rendering Engine": `Settings` -> `Experimental` -> `Use new Layout Rendering Engine`.

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62940389/10089719

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be not complete relatable to you, However, If you want to add new Icon in Android Studio-
Right Click on "App" folder.
Select the option "New".
then Click "Vector Asset".

In this case, you will able to find new vector asset and can reuse that.

Comment: Actually this is what I did. But everytime I tried, these icon become weird. It happened in the preview, but when I builded it to emulator it did not happen. I just do not understand why it become like that

Comment: Create again the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the icons that are weird, restart android studio and create all the icons you need again.

Maybe another solution could be updating to a newer version of android studio, if the current version is not the last.