# Android Studio 4 incorrect vector drawable preview

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.0

After update to Android Studio 4.0, all my vector icons display wrong on the preview screen. But they look normal after running an application on the device. It concerns all vector icons: imported on the previous version of the Android Studio, imported on the new version, imported from svg file, and imported in Android Studio as clip art.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

[image: sample of wrong icon]

How to fix it?

Comment: Your image is transparent?

Comment: Some paths with transparency, some not, but preview is always incorrect

Comment: Same problem here with Android studio 4.0. Just tried Android Studio 4.1 beta02 and same problem persists. Ubuntu 18.04.4

Comment: Same issue on Android studio 4.0.1 and Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon.

Comment: Seems like it was fixed in Android Studio 4.1

Comment: This is a [reported bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167164437), should be fixed in 4.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably because you have a non-default locale (to check run `locale` in terminal). In particular `LC_NUMERIC`. If that's the case, to fix the issue run the studio with e.g. `LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`.

Comment: Brilliant! That solved the issue! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 16):

I fixed it by disabling `Settings` -> `Experimental` -> `Use new Layout Rendering Engine`.

Answer (score -5):

In your build.gradle file

```
android { 
          defaultConfig
                      {
                           vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true 
                      }
        }

dependencies {  
             compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0' 
             }
```

and use ***app:srcCompat***  instead  of ***android:src***

Invalid Caches/Restart

then try to create a new drawable vector its should works..